# Cloudant View Unusual Conditional Behavior with Dates

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Found some peculiar behavior was wondering if anyone could help me to understand it so to avoid similar issues in the future.

Creating a cloudant view I want to return only records with a timestamp of the current day.

I was having a hard time getting it to work and found the difference is in having a space before the end of the if condition.

See below for working and not working

```
 if (new Date(Date.parse(doc.details.timestamp)).setHours(0,0,0,0) === new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) ){
```

Works to check the current date against the Cloudant doc date

```
 if (new Date(Date.parse(doc.details.timestamp)).setHours(0,0,0,0) === new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)){
```

Does not work to check the date against the Cloudant doc date

Full working view below for context

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.details.location){
    if (new Date(Date.parse(doc.details.timestamp)).setHours(0,0,0,0) === new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) ){
      emit(doc.details.location.toLowerCase(), { "location": doc.details.location.toLowerCase(), "status": doc.details.status, "user": doc.details.username, "time": doc.details.timestamp})
    }
   }
 }
```

All the best,

Scott.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this may be to do with the execution date/time of the `if` statement rather than the space involved.

The `map` function needs to be deterministic regardless of execution time.

It *looks* like you are guessing that the `map` function is running at query time (so `new Date` would emit today's date). Instead, it runs at indexing time, so the value of `new Date` is whatever the datetime is when the indexing happens. As indexing runs at a different time to document insertion (sometime between insert and when the view is queried), using any form of value that changes with time will produce unpredictable results.

I suspect therefore the space is co-incidental and instead the output of `new Date` is changing, and so altering what's emitted into your view.

For your problem -- querying for things "today" -- I think you want to instead emit a key like `[location, year, month, day]`. Your map function would look like:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.details.location) {
    var l = doc.details.location.toLowerCase();
    var d = Date.parse(doc.details.timestamp);
    emit([l, d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()], { 
      "location": l, 
      "status": doc.details.status, 
      "user": doc.details.username, 
      "time": doc.details.timestamp
    });
  }
}
```

As JavaScript uses 0-based indexes for the month,  to query for all items at location `Bristol` on today, 2-Feb-2017, you'd use  `key=["bristol",2017,1,2]` to in your query to the view.